# Using AngularJS and Selecting in Select Leads to Selection Spelled Out

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a `<select>` in my HTML and am using ngOptions to populate it.  When an item from the drop down is selected, the `<select>` is redrawn with the new option broken into one letter per option.

So if I select the item "Cars" from a `<select>`, then the new options are "C", "a", "r", and "s".

See the issue at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WilliamHerbert/2hyqg74a/8/).

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="genders" ng-options="gender as gender for gender in genders"></select>
  </div>
</body>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.genders = ["Female", "Male"];
}
```

The JSFiddle is using Angular 1.2.1, but I am getting the same problem with 1.3.5.  I'm also not using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your ng-model to "gender" things should work fine.

Currently the model is referencing the array named genders, and appears to take the selection and do a split() on the string. Upon making your selection, your "genders" array is now equivalent to the string "Female" or "Male", which is why the selection is changed to the individual characters.

Alternatively, you can change your ng-model to something like "selectedGender".

Here is [a fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppaz9fn9/1/) using "gender" instead of "genders."

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="gender" ng-options="gender for gender in genders"></select>
</div>
```